# Naive Bayes partial_fit() using over 16 GB of RAM for a single sample

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I'm using Scikit-Learn with the `MultinomialNB` classifer, and for memory reasons I'm doing [out-of-core learning](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#scaling-with-instances-using-out-of-core-learning)

My current attempt is this:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 1
clf = MultinomialNB()
vec, le = train_transformers()
classes = le.transform(le.classes_)
data = corpus('examples') # This is a generator that returns (x, y) tuples

while True:
    x, y = get_minibatch(data, BATCH_SIZE)
    if len(x) == 0:
        break
    x_tran = vec.transform(x)
    print("X Transformed")
    print(x_tran)
    y_tran = le.transform(y)
    print("Y Transformed")
    print(y_tran)
    clf.partial_fit(x_tran, y_tran, classes=classes)

    print("Loop")
```

This produces the following output:

```
X Transformed
  (0, 74352)    1
  (0, 116843)   1
  (0, 118228)   1
  (0, 129580)   1
  (0, 164004)   1
  (0, 188698)   1
  (0, 203277)   1
  (0, 204435)   1
  (0, 205407)   1
  (0, 217024)   1
Y Transformed
[8016]
```

All of these outputs make total sense, and the memory footprint stays under 1 gb...and then the `partial_fit()` starts, and keeps increasing memory until I hit 16gb and the process dies.

What am I doing wrong for a single sample to do this? I was hoping to have a BATCH_SIZE of over 1000, but apparently that isn't possible...?

Comment: batch_size = 1 is the smallest batch size? it should work if oyu set it to 100

Comment: This same problem happens with BATCH_SIZE=100, 200, 1000 etc